# Validating values present in Python List using in operator

Tags: python, list, loops, if-statement

I have written below simple code to check values present in Python List (unique_status):

```
if "Match" in unique_status and "Mismatch" in unique_status:
    print("Match and Mismatch both found.")
elif "Match" in unique_status:
    print("Only Match found.")
elif "Mismatch" in unique_status:
    print("Only Mismatch found.")
else:
    print("Something else is also present.)

For Value in Unique_Status = ['Match'], I am getting "Only Match Found"
For Value in Unique_Status = ['Mismatch'], I am getting "Only Mismatch Found"
For Value in Unique_Status = ['Match','Mismatch'], I am getting "Match and Mismatch both found."
```

However when list contains some other value also, like ['Match','Mismatch','XYZ'], then else part is not getting executed.
What condition/modification is required in my code so that it checks the Unique_Status List, and executes the else condition, in case some other value is also present apart from Match and Mismatch.

Comment: That's not a simple "else", of course.  The `else` is only checked if all the other conditions are false.  You need to use a separate loop after the `if` block is ended, to check whether any word in the list is not a match.  I'll show an example.

Answer (score 0):

```
if "Match" in unique_status and "Mismatch" in unique_status:
    print("Match and Mismatch both found.")
elif "Match" in unique_status:
    print("Only Match found.")
elif "Mismatch" in unique_status:
    print("Only Mismatch found.")

if any( word not in ['Match','Mismatch'] for word in unique_status ):
    print("Something else is also present.)
```

### Followup

If you want just ONE thing printed, you should have said that.  In that case, "in" is clearly the wrong operator.  You need to be looking for equality:

```
if unique_status == ["Match"]:
    print("Only Match found.")
elif unique_status == ["Mismatch"]:
    print("Only Mismatch found.")
elif set(unique_status) == set(["Match","Mismatch"]):
    print("Match and Mismatch both found.")
else:
    print("Something else is also present.)
```

Comment: For this code, when we have value in unique_status = ['Match','Mismatch','XYZ'], value of both if statements are getting printed. Should I write the if statement you wrote at last as the first if statement and rest all as elif's ?

Comment: You need to tell us EXACTLY what you want.  What you implied in your problem description is that you wanted to know when any of those words were found, AND you wanted to know if there was something else.  However, surely you can figure out how to get what you want from what we've posted here.

Comment: Yes figured it out..Thanks for the help 

Answer (score 0):

Because your first **if condition** is getting satisfied if `unique_status = ['Match','Mismatch','XYZ']`
Hence, the else is not working